# Who first used the term 'heuristic' in a cognitive science context?

Tags: reference-request, decision-making

I seem to recall that Herbert Simon borrowed the term from computer science, but I cannot remember the initial paper in which he made use of this borrowing.

A google scholar search reveals some papers from 1957-1958, for instance [this one](http://www.u-picardie.fr/~furst/docs/Newell_Simon_Heuristic_Problem_Solving_1958.pdf), but I really felt there was something from earlier in the 1950s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A nice summary about heuristics can be found in:

Gigerenzer, G., & Gaissmaier, W. (2011). [Heuristic Decision Making](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-psych-120709-145346). Annual Review of Psychology, 62, 451–482.

In this review "satisficing" (accepting a good enough option) is referred to an earlier reference than the 1958 you cite:
Simon, H.A. (1955). [A behavioral model of rational choice](http://qje.oxfordjournals.org/content/69/1/99.short). Q. J. Econ. 69:99–118.

In their (Gigerenzer & Gaissmaier) history part they also refer to Einstein using the term in his 1905 paper on quantum physics, stating that the view he presented was "incomplete but highly useful".

Answer (score 6):

His very first use of heuristic beyond computer science (he won the Turing award in Comp. Science) is from [1946](https://www.jstor.org/stable/973030?&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

The Proverbs of Administration
Herbert A. Simon, *Public Administration Review*, Vol. 6, No. 1 (Winter, 1946), pp. 53-67

> If so, the evidence that it is an
>   error has never been marshalled or published-apart
>   from loose heuristic arguments
>   like that quoted above

Comment: One of my favorite scientists came up with one of my favorite words. Excellent!